# Add a tiny number to duplicate value to differentiate

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a list names and numbers and after highlighting there seems to be a fair bit of duplicate values. Does anyone know an easy way to add a small amount to change the numbers? For example if I have two 77.5's, I would add a small amount to the duplicate so I would get 77.50001 and 77.5. And for more than two duplicates. (77.50003, 77.50002, 77.50001, 77.5)

Answer (score 0):

`=A1&(ROW(A1)/100000)` will add one hundred thousandth of the (unique) row number the reference is in. Just be aware that at rows 10, 100, 1000 it "eats" more of the "space" between it and your original number. Advantages: Simple. "Records" the original row number. Disadvantage: ALL numbers will be affected, not just the duplicate ones.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the previous answer, this won't affect any non-duplicate numbers.

Assuming your numeric values are in column A, starting at row 1, I'd type the following into B1 then click it down the length of column A:

=(countif(A$1:A1,A1)-1)*0.000001+A1

This counts how many times the duplicate value features from the beginning of column A down to the cell being evaluated. Subtracting the 1 means the very first instance won't be affected (1-1)*0.000001 = 0 + A1. This is also, probably obviously, true for all unique values. Thereafter, you'll be adding 0.000001, 0.000002, 0.000003 etc. each time a duplicate value is encountered.